# Redirection to a mobile app from the webview of the app itself in React Native

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, webview, oauth-2.0

I'm building an android application which requires authentication from an external auth provider.So I'm using [react-native-oauth](https://github.com/fullstackreact/react-native-oauth/) package to handle this.

The redirect_uri defined is a deep link which should ideally open my app itself after successful authentication.But the WebView seems to not handle this redirection and I'm getting response as 404-page not found.

This is the service that I have written to handle the auth:

```
    const manager = new OAuthManager('<app_name>')

    manager.addProvider({
         'provider': {
                  auth_version: '2.0', 
                  authorize_url:'<auth-url>',
                  access_token_url: '<auth-url>/token',
                  callback_url: 'http://localhost/provider',
         }
    });

    manager.configure({
       provider: {
           client_id: '<id>',
           client_secret: '<secret>',
           redirect_uri: '<redirect-uri>' //DEEP LINK HERE
      }
    });
   module.exports = {
      authManager: () => {
      manager.authorize('<provider>')
                        .then(resp => console.log(resp))
                        .catch(err => console.log(err));    
                    }
   }
```

Also I have defined my intent-filter as specified in the Android docs on [how to declare the deep links for your apps](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking.html).The deep link works fine when opened with Linking.openURL() from the app components.

Any help in this is much appreciated.

Comment: What is the redirect uri you have used? Also when you get the 404 what is the link in the webview?

Comment: @TarunLalwani The redirect uri is app.<app_name>.com/auth and the scheme is **https** .The link in the web view is the same as well

Comment: Please provide me the source code and assign me the job.

Comment: @Codesingh I can give you specifics of the issues

Comment: ok i'm looking forward for it

Comment: check this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/38991019/2809351

Comment: you can use this strategy: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25672330/how-to-enable-deep-linking-in-webview-on-android-app. This is the native code but you can do the same thing in react-native also using callbacks like onLoadStart.

Comment: I wouldn't use this library because it asks you to store secret keys on client side.

Answer (score 13):

You can't directly set redirect_uri to your mobile app ( because most auth providers doesn't support custom OAuth scheme ).

But you can create some web page that will accept redirect from OAuth providers and will open your app ( and send all redirect params, like `token` ).

For example you create page `https://example.com/oauth/`, and set `callback_url` to `https://example.com/oauth/XXXXX_provider`, so when user will be redirected to page `https://example.com/oauth/XXXXX_provider&token=xxx` it will open you app  using `appName://example/oauth/google?token=xxx`

You can handle `appName://example/oauth/google?token=xxx`  using  [Deeplink](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking.html) ( it will open your mobile app when it is installed on device )

Example of page to handle redirects:

```html
<html><head></head><body>
<p>Please wait while we redirect you to Your APP NAME...</p>
<p><a href="javascript:redirectToApp()">Open appname</a></p>
<script>
  var redirectToApp = function() {
    var scheme = "appnameapp";
    var openURL = "appname" + window.location.pathname + window.location.search + window.location.hash;
    var iOS = /iPad|iPhone|iPod/.test(navigator.userAgent);
    var Android = /Android/.test(navigator.userAgent);
    var newLocation;
    if (iOS) {
      newLocation = scheme + ":" + openURL;
    } else if (Android) {
      newLocation = "intent://" + openURL + "#Intent;scheme=" + scheme + ";package=com.appnameapp;end";
    } else {
      newLocation = scheme + "://" + openURL;
    }
    console.log(newLocation)
    window.location.replace(newLocation);
  }
  window.onload = redirectToApp;
</script>


</body></html>
```

Comment: I created something like this. It avoids all mess with RN libraries such as `react-native-fbsdk` and `react-native-google-signi`. This way, you can implement everything on a server-side and pass an API token to your mobile app with a deep link.

Answer (score 3):

WebView by default doesn't share cookies/session data with Safari/Chrome. So it is not ideal for login flow since it doesn't use the existing logged in session in Chrome/Safari.

Expo provides a [WebBrowser api](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/webbrowser.html) that will open Safari/Chrome instead of webview. Note that it opens Safari/Chrome inside the app, instead of redirecting you the browser using `Linking`. So users always have a button in the browser to get back to your app.

You can use `WebBrowser.openAuthSessionAsync(url)` to open a secure session which shares cookie/session info with the native browser in the device.

Expo also provides another api called [AuthSession](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/auth-session.html) that simplifies a lot of boilerplate and provides a simple api.