# Android Google Drive OAuth with CustomTabsIntent

Tags: android, oauth, google-oauth, deep-linking, android-customtabs

I have been trying to get google OAuth to work on android and I am continuously hitting roadblocks.

Right now, in my manifest, I've added the custom url scheme and host for my redirect URL, like so:

[image: OAuth custom scheme and host]

When I try to use that URL scheme in the Google OAuth intent, I get the following error:

[image: URL scheme error]

After some googling, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38995410/1846536) answer on stackoverflow, telling me to reformat my URL scheme to `com.myapp.myscheme:/oauth`, so I set the redirect_uri to `com.loop.loop:/oauth`, since `com.loop` is my package name, `loop` is my scheme, and `oauth` is my host.

After trying that, I get this error:

[image: Redirect URI mismatch]

This error tells me that I need to register my redirect URI somewhere, so I go to the Google API console where I registered my client_id. However, there is literally no place to register my redirect URI:

[image: Google API Console]

For some reason, using `com.loop:/oauth` works, but it doesn't redirect back to my app after authorizing. Instead, it just goes to the Google homepage.

Here is the code I'm using to run the chrome custom tabs:

```
CustomTabsIntent.Builder builder = new CustomTabsIntent.Builder();
CustomTabsIntent chromeIntent = builder.build();
chromeIntent.launchUrl(this, Uri.parse(url));
```

This is the OAuth URL I'm using:

`https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth`

I have no idea what I'm supposed to do here, and the documentation is not very helpful. I'm also aware there is an Android Google Auth library, but I'm not interested in that because that is specific to Google, and I'm just trying to make a generic OAuth controller. I have also tried using a WebView, but Google doesn't allow OAuth through a WebView. Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I was able to figure it out from [this](https://blog.cloudrail.com/solving-disallowed_useragent-for-google-services/).

Apparently for google oauth, the intent filter must look like this:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="[YourPackageName]" />
</intent-filter>
```

Replace `[YourPackageName]` with your android app's package name, and use `[YourPackageName]:/oauth` as your redirect URL (the oauth part can be named anything)

So uh... thanks google for documenting that nowhere

Comment: Perfect. Thanks!

Comment: Link is broken, if you could update it, it would be awesome

Comment: When in doubt, put it in the wayback machine. But also, I've pretty much put all the relevant info in this answer
https://web.archive.org/web/20190222161534/https://blog.cloudrail.com/solving-disallowed_useragent-for-google-services/